# Tichu probability

Tags: probability

A deck of cards plus 4 special cards (A,B,C,D for a total 56 cards) is divided to 4 players.
Each player gets 14 cards.
a) What is the probability that all special cards will go to one player and 
b) what is the probability special cards A and D will go to different players?

Answer (score 1):

I would say - to solve using a hypergeometric probability distribution:

a) P(cards A,B,C,D to one player):

$\displaystyle P(a) = 4\cdot\frac{{4\choose4}{52\choose10}}{{56\choose14}}$

b) 1 - P(cards A,D to one player):

$\displaystyle P(b) = 1-4\cdot\frac{{2\choose2}{54\choose12}}{{56\choose14}}$